# Power bi line and stacked column chart custom series don't show position property

Tags: powerbi

I am using power bi Version: 2.65.5313.5141 64-bit (January 2019). I have created line and stacked column chart. Every thing working fine. But i am unable to fixed line values position.From this link
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sj4cOzJpyZI&list=LLDdQWSt2mmHAF0AgewyJwKQ&index=3&t=114s
i have find a solution.But another problem arise. This link shows customize series into data labels where show position property for column values but my power bi desktop customize series don't show any position property. Can any body tell me why this happen into my power bi desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome!

Looks like your Power BI could be out of date. Update it to the latest version [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=58494) and try again.